# Groovy - access element of json

Tags: json, dictionary, jenkins, groovy

I have this json output:

```
{"UT":{
  "test_results":[
   [
     {
         "branches": "8",
          "build": "normal"
     },
     {
         "branches": "8",
         "build": "normal"
     }
   ]
  ],
 }
}
```

I use this piece of code:

```
            def json = JsonOutput.toJson(br2)
            def parsed = new groovy.json.JsonSlurper().parseText(json)
```

I parse the text but how could I access the values of build?

Answer (score 1):

The `JsonSlurper().parseText(json)` call will return a LazyMap. From there, you can interact with it as you would with any map. The offcial groovy docs have an approachable explainer [here](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/next/html/documentation/working-with-collections.html#Collections-Maps).

In your case, there are multiple ways to get the values of build. Your json structure seems to have an extra list wrapping the `test_results` objects. If this is constant, you can do something like:

```
assert parsed["UT"]["test_results"][0]["branches"] == ["8", "8"]
```

alternatively, you can simply flatten the values returned by direct access:

```
assert parsed["UT"]["test_results"]["branches"].flatten() == ["8", "8"]
```